# nomodeset not working when GRUB menu doesn't show on Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, reboot, nomodeset

I had to edit the GRUB configuration file to default to use `nomodeset`, but I have found that this option doesn't seem to get used unless the GRUB menu shows. I can try pressing the shift key each time I boot, but this is obviously cumbersome. Is there any way to make this option work regardless of whether or not the menu shows?

**Update**: This problem still occurs in 16.04.1.

Comment: What options other than a 'hard reboot' are you referring to?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I'm referring to the distinction made in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reboot_(computing)) Wikipedia article. I would like to be able to perform a soft reboot (i.e. by choosing "Reboot" from the Logout/Shutdown menu) and still have `nomodeset` work.

Comment: Are you saying that grub doesn't run in that case?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I assume that GRUB is still running in the case of a soft reboot, but the menu isn't showing, and, possibly in conjunction with this, it doesn't seem to be respecting the default option that would be in the menu. Maybe I misunderstand the booting process and GRUB, though.

Comment: I would be surprised if you do any kind of boot without grub. If you can edit your question to give a detailed, specific case of when it works, and another detailed, specificcase of when it does not, you are more likely to get help here.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I've realized through investigating again that it seems to ultimately come down to whether or not the GRUB menu shows. If it shows before boot, then `nomodeset` gets used. If it doesn't show, it seems that `nomodeset` does not get used. How it was shutdown seems to actually be irrelevant.

Comment: That may indeed be a clue. On my systems the grub menu is displayed based on the settings in /etc/default/grub so it either displays every boot, or not, depending on how I have it set.  The only exception is that sometime the grub menu appears on its own after a serious failure during the previous boot process.

Comment: So I would try to figure out why the grub menu does not appear consistently, if you have correctly set it to do so.